# Jack audio not working properly with cadence

Tags: linux, audio, debian, pulse-audio

I have tried to set up the audio on my Debian linux computer in order that I can use ardour and get sound from/to that,  and still be able to watch youtube videos etc. on Firefox. I have installed cadence in order to get this working, after reading that that was a simple way of doing it. 
Audio works fine for Ardour when I start Ardour (and it starts jack for me), but that doesn't start cadence so no bridging occurs from pulse audio to Jack so I can't here anything from any software that doesn't directly use jack,  ie Firefox.
However if I try and start cadence first no audio can be heard at all from anything,  not even ardour,  unless I stop jack from inside cadence and let ardour start it itself leading back to my initial problem. 
My question is firstly,  what tests can I do to help you locate the exact issue?
Secondly how would you recommend going about this,  in order to achieve what I wanted using cadence (as that is what I have started doing so might as well continue if I can) ? 
Thirdly if using cadence means that I always have to start it manually rather than have it automated whenever a program tried to start jack (as ardour does), is there another reasonably easy was of doing this (or easier way if I have chosen and overly complex route).
Thanks in advance,  and sorry for the lack of test results in this initial post.

HOWEVER THINGS I HAVE TESTED:
`lsmod | grep audio`
And 
`Lspci | grep audio`
Do nothing,  however
`Sudo aplay - l`
Shows my sound card as expected.

Alsamixer is not muted in anyway.

As far as I can tell (in my n00bishness)  I would say that I am more likely to have installed too much stuff that has ended up competing rather than not having enough...who knows how I will manage to remove all the stuff I don't actually need afterwards!

Thanks in advance for your time and effort :)